# Copy missing objects from one store to another (with CoreData)

Tags: core-data, object, copy, store

I have a sqlite db in my project resources folder and I want to copy all objects of an entity of that store into the users db store when they are missing.

I googled already a lot and many people talk about NSMigrationManager, direct SQLite3-statements and on and on. But what is the best approach to do this? Is there a way to do this with CoreData directly? I would be very thankful if you could give me a code snippet which explains your solution.

THANKS
Phil

Answer (score 2):

Yes this can be done directly.  The steps are:

1. Stand up the target store
2. Stand up the source store
3. Create a new object in the target store
4. Reference the object in the source store
5. Copy the attributes from the source object to the destination object
6. Repeat 3-5 until all objects are copied over
7. Save target store

The code to do this is in my [Core Data](http://pragprog.com/titles/mzcd/core-data) book.  You can find the relevant copy code in Chapter 9.

Comment: Might want to offer @Philipp a discount to accept your answer. Apart from that, not very informative to the rest of the community, is it? Especially step 4. And 5.

Comment: Hi Marcus if you can elaborate it a bit, it will be more helpful !